# Quasar 2: Using v-ripple directive in SFC defined with <script setup>

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, quasar

I'm trying Quasar v2.7.1 framework (with Vue 3, TypeScript, Pinia and Router) and want to use the  syntax to define a SFCs how it's recomended in the official Vue 3 Docs. But as soon as I change component with v-ripple directive on any element inside it, I face following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')
> at updateModifiers (Ripple.js?v=eddf1594:65:45)
> at beforeMount (Ripple.js?v=eddf1594:112:9)
> at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)
> at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)
> at invokeDirectiveHook (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2791:13)
> at mountElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5180:13)
> at processElement (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5110:13)
> at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5030:21)
> at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5582:21)
> at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:185:25)

If v-ripple directive removed - the problem doesn't appear again.

To reproduce just change the EssentialLink.vue component of the default Quasar boilerplate to

```
    <template>
     <q-item clickable tag="a" target="_blank" v-ripple>
        <q-item-section v-if="icon" avatar>
          <q-icon :name="props.icon" />
        </q-item-section>
    
        <q-item-section>
          <q-item-label>{{ title }}</q-item-label>
          <q-item-label caption>{{ caption }}</q-item-label>
        </q-item-section>
      </q-item>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    const props = defineProps<{
      title: string;
      caption: string;
      link: string;
      icon: string;
    }>();
    </script>
```

The question is: is it my fault and I must declair v-ripple directive somehow else. Or it's a bug?

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vite-typescript-quasar-starter-jbuvde?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue).

Comment: It's very strange. I tried it many times and for me it's easy reproducible. Maybe it depends on environment? I'm using Win10 and yarn as package manager. Also last LTS version of Node.js

Comment: And I took a look on your test project. My quasar project looks a bit different. I'm using "yarn create quasar" command in CMD to scaffold a project. I prepared a git repo to test https://github.com/LevShipulin/quasar-test

Comment: As noted in [`quasar#13154`](https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/issues/13154), a workaround is to downgrade to `vue@3.2.31`. [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasar-workaround-v-ripple-issue) (Note Quasar seems flaky on StackBlitz, so the demo might not work, but that's not caused by the `vue` downgrade)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and as @tony19 suggested just downgraded to vue@3.2.31 and it works.